# intersection of radical extensions of Q

Tags: field-theory

Are there radical extensions $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq R_1$ and  $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq R_2$ such that $R_1 \cap R_2$ is not radical over $\mathbb{Q}$? My guess is that one can find a such example, but I could not come up with one so far.